# Is Form a Presentational Component or a Container Component

Tags: reactjs, vuejs2

[This](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) is the article that everyone refers to. It basically says that all API calls should be made by a Container/Smart component, and the data should be passed to the Presentational/Dumb component.

**Here is my use case:**

Suppose there is dialog-box/modal that has a form in it(shown below). Now when the field `Access Type` changes, the options in the `Permissions` dropdown also changes and the data is fetched from the server.[image: Create User dialog box]

**My questions are:**

1) Is this dialog box a container or a presentational component? Or in other words, should this component make an API call to create a new user or should this be wrapped in a Container component that makes an API call?

2) If you assume that this dialog box is a Presentational component, then, every time, `Access Type` changes, how would the API call to fetch `Permissions` list be made? Is firing events the only solution?

3) If this form is a presentational component, then, what would the `onSubmitHandler` do when user clicks on the submit button: Just fire an event to the Container component with the form payload?

Answer (score 1):

1) I can only speak from my own experience, and would say that the form is a presentational component, but should be wrapped in a container that handles the API calls.

2) Again, from own experience, i think onChange should only update the components internal state, and have a "submit"-event on onBlur, so when the user changes fields, the permissions will be fetched.

3) The onSubmitHandler should atleast do a `event.preventDefault()`, so the page doesn't reload, and then use a callback it got from the parent container.

Comment: `so when the user changes fields, the permissions will be fetched.`


The API call to fetch `Permissions` should be made by the container or the form component itself?

Comment: Yeah, made by the container.